# Organize data with spaces from column to a separate row sequentially for any unique names

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

here is the problem:

[image]

this is just a small tid bit of the larger problem, I wrote it out like this so I can then reverse engineer the solution for my bigger project. If someone can help that would be really awesome. Thank you!

I really don't know where to turn to except here.

My colleagues suggested using =UNIQUE equation, but I have no idea how that would work since I am trying to use this code in a grander piece of code that will process the data from each row. I just now need a way to sequentially organize any unique names it will come up on. I can try to make the names a requirement to be used in a list somewhere but if we don't have to and just look for that unique name and create a separate row for that data that would be awesome.

the following code is what i will be modifying to include any solution from here it already goes row by row for the data. the users name will be in column "U".

```
Public Sub SortPriorities()

Dim priorityBlocks(127, 2)
Dim p As Variant
Dim l As Variant
Dim thisRow As Long
Dim nextRow As Long
Dim blockCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim swapped As Boolean

' Find the last used row
nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row

' Insert a dummy end
Cells(nextRow + 2, "A").Value = "@"

' Find all the blocks
thisRow = 4
blockCount = 0
Do While Cells(thisRow, "A").Value <> "@"
    priorityBlocks(blockCount, 0) = Cells(thisRow, "A").Value
    priorityBlocks(blockCount, 1) = thisRow
    nextRow = Cells(thisRow, "A").End(xlDown).Row
    priorityBlocks(blockCount, 2) = nextRow - thisRow
    thisRow = nextRow
    blockCount = blockCount + 1
Loop
    
' Bubble sort
Do
    swapped = False
    For i = 1 To blockCount - 1
        If priorityBlocks(i - 1, 0) > priorityBlocks(i, 0) Then
            swapped = True
            
            'modification to work with date range: 2/13/2023 - Gru
            If Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "A").Value = "1" Then
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AB") = "=(ACTUALSTARTDATE + (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),17))/8))"
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AC") = "=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),17))/8)+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),28)))"
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AC").Name = "ENDDATE" & Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "A").Value
            End If
            
            Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "A").Resize(priorityBlocks(i, 2), 1).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Cut
            Cells(priorityBlocks(i - 1, 1), "A").EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Insert xlShiftDown
            p = priorityBlocks(i - 1, 0)
            l = priorityBlocks(i - 1, 2)
            priorityBlocks(i - 1, 0) = priorityBlocks(i, 0)
            priorityBlocks(i - 1, 2) = priorityBlocks(i, 2)
            priorityBlocks(i, 0) = p
            priorityBlocks(i, 1) = priorityBlocks(i - 1, 1) + priorityBlocks(i - 1, 2)
            priorityBlocks(i, 2) = l
        End If
    Next i
    DoEvents
Loop Until swapped = False

Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).ClearContents

    'modification to work with date range: 2/13/2023 - Gru
    For i = 1 To blockCount - 1
            If Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "A").Value = "1" Then
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AB") = "=(ACTUALSTARTDATE + (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),17))/8))"
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AC") = "=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),17))/8)+(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),28)))"
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AC").Name = "ENDDATE" & Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "A").Value
            Else
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AC").Name = "ENDDATE" & Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "A").Value
                Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "AB") = "=(ENDDATE" & Cells(priorityBlocks(i, 1), "A").Value - 1 & " + (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),17))/8))"
            End If
    Next i

Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not link to files in your question. Instead, include any code you want others to see in your question.

Comment: This is a problem that Power Query will help you with in a far better way than VBA. Select the table and click Get Data on the Data tab.

Comment: What did you try with the suggested `=UNIQUE()`? Would this not do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly this does what you mean.

```
=LET(colAC,SORT(DROP(CHOOSECOLS(A:C,1,3),3)),
     colA,INDEX(colAC,,1),
     colC,INDEX(colAC,,2),
     unq,UNIQUE(FILTER(colC,colC<>"")),
     prio, DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,unq,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(colA,colC=y))))),""),1),
HSTACK(unq,prio))
```

Especially the `prio` part makes the calculation slower, but it spills the sorted task priorities for each unique user (also sorted by priority).

Or transposed:

```
=LET(colAC,SORT(DROP(CHOOSECOLS(A:C,1,3),3)),colA,INDEX(colAC,,1),colC,INDEX(colAC,,2),u,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(colC,colC<>""))),n,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,u,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,FILTER(colA,colC=y)))),""),,1),VSTACK(u,n))
```

Comment: this works amazing! wow, i have so much to learn from this.

Comment: looking at it more, this is the golden formula that can be used practically for anything. Everybody should learn this.

Comment: Yeah, REDUCE is very useful, but can also make calculation slow in many cases. But if you need to spill 2D dynamically, this is often formula to get to a solution.

Comment: Question, I tried everything to make this work by organizing the data vertically instead of horizontally and for the life of me i have no idea how to do it. Can you create another formula for me to do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. Didn't the formula get you the desired result?

Comment: Yes the formula got the desired result, im trying to change it now to sort with the names up top as headers and the numbers to sort down under each name in order.

Comment: Ah, just wrap the formula in transpose()?

Comment: thank you!

=TRANSPOSE(HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER('Task List'!A:A&","&'Task List'!U:U&","&'Task List'!Q:Q&","&(TEXT('Task List'!AB:AB,"mm/dd/yyyy"))&","&(TEXT('Task List'!AC:AC,"mm/dd/yyyy")),'Task List'!D:D<>""),0),",",,TRUE))))

Comment: Also added a version in the edit